# How can I ignore .svn directories when using sloccount?

Tags: svn

I'm trying to use `sloccount` from within [hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) to gather statistics on our codebase, however by default `sloccount` collects information on *all* files, even those which are "hidden" (eg. `.hideme`). This means the statistics are skewed since they include numbers from files within the `.svn` directories.

Is there any way I can tell `sloccount` to correctly ignore any files/directories which start with a `.`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My final approach was to remove the `.svn` directories from the sed output:

```
sloccount --wide --details $DIR | sed "/\/\.svn\//d" > sloccount.sc
```

Comment: Dave's solution doesn't waste time on files in the `.svn` directories in the first place.

Answer (score 8):

This syntax is easier to maintain and to extend (which is highly important when you need to exclude several directories):

```
sloccount --duplicates --wide --details . | grep -v -e '.svn' > sloccount.sc
```

Example of exclusions chain:

```
sloccount --duplicates --wide --details . | grep -v -e '.svn' -e 'thirdparty'  > sloccount.sc
```

**NB:** I use it and it works on my Jenkins

Comment: Should be careful with this, it really just filters the output not updating any totals.

Answer (score 7):

You could edit the source code of sloccount to not search in directories that begin with a period.  Otherwise, here is something I cooked up on the command line.  Basically, you can specify a list of file paths on the command line as arguments to sloccount and it will analyze only those files.  So this will find all files under PWD, excluding hidden files, and then pass them as argument to sloccount.

```
find . \( ! -regex '.*/\..*' \) -type f | \
tr '\n' ' ' | \
xargs sloccount
```

Comment: Are you sure you need the `tr` command?  How about passing the `-print0` flag to `find` and the `-0` flag  to `xargs` to handle paths and filenames with spaces?

Comment: Use find-included xargs support: `-exec sloccount {} \+`

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
find . -path '*/.*' -prune -o -type f -exec sloccount {} \+
```

`-exec` avoids the `xargs` hacks seen in some of the other replies. This is the find-included xargs support. No need to run regexps, globbing is enough. Pruning subdirs is also more efficient.

**Update:** also, you may want to upgrade to a more recent subversion. New checkout format (after `svn upgrade`) uses only a single `.svn` directory, so usually you can just do `sloccount src` now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following ant target to build a "sloccount.sc" without files in ".svn":

```xml
<target name="sloccount">
    <echo message="build sloccount report" />
    <exec executable="sloccount" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="--details" />
        <arg value="--wide" />
        <arg value="source_folder" />
        <redirector output="sloccount.sc">
            <outputfilterchain>
                <linecontains negate="true">
                    <contains value=".svn" />
                </linecontains>
            </outputfilterchain>
        </redirector>
    </exec>
</target>
```

Simply replace "source_folder" by the name of the source folder you want to scan and tell Jenkins to build ant target "sloccount".

Note that this requires ant 1.7.1 or later.

Answer (score 1):

One can ignore `.svn` directories by collecting files from all other directories using find:

```
find . -not -wholename '*/.svn/*' -type f | xargs sloccount
```